# TYPO3 extension: records created in BE don't appear in FE, but records created in FE don't appear in BE

Tags: typo3

In TYPO3 8.7.9 i'm working on an extension. Normally it should be possible to create records in BE and FE but it seems that the records created in BE aren't listed in the Frontend view. But if i create a record in the FE, it is only shown in the FE view, but doesn't appear in the BE. I've checked the controllers and everything seems to be fine. The list action accesses the specific repository and assigns it to the view:

```
public function listAction()
    {
        $termins = $this->terminRepository->findAll();
        $this->view->assign('termins', $termins);
    }
```

Edit: I've just checked the mysql database entries and they contain ALL 3 entries, the two i made in BE and one i made in FE, but in the FE only one appears, in the BE the other two appear. I've never experienced that kind of behaviour.

Edit2: Of course i injected the repository.

Comment: Can you check the field pid of each entry? Are there differences you expected?

Comment: The pid of reords created in the BE was 1... In FE 0. Changing it to 0 made them appear in the FE as well. But why and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use default value of storage pid for new records with TypoScript like

```
config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes.Vendorname\Kundentermine\Domain\Model\Termin.newRecordStoragePid = 1
```

You can add this line in a file in your extension kundentermine/ext_typoscript_setup.txt which will be loaded automaticly into root page.

Set also in your default typoscript setup

```
plugin.tx_kundentermine_pi.persistence.storagePid = 1
```

to ensure, your Vendorname\Kundentermine\Domain\Repository\TerminRepository class fetches entries from correct storage page.

Adapt vendor, extension and model name...

Se also https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/b-ExtbaseReference/Index.html#persistence

Comment: It doesnt seem to work (maybe i'm doing something wrong?)... I put the ext_typoscript_setup.txt into that directory: /typo3conf/ext/kundentermine/

Comment: I've edited my answer. Got entries correct storage page uid in DB table? Are they visible in backend after creating via frontend? Or are they just not shown in frontend, after creating via frontend?

Comment: By "default typoscript setup" you mean the page TS config or something else? Sry i'm pretty inexperienced with TYPO3 and still learning. Basically: When creating a record in the BE the pid is 1 and the record doesn't show up in the FE. When changing it to 0 it does. If i create a record in FE suddenly the pid is also 1 and the record doesn't show up in the FE. Before the pid was 0 when creating it in the FE (i guess that is because of the changes you suggested - but that doesn't solve my problem).

Comment: Hmm... It seems i've solved the problem by setting the storagePid in my constants.ts to 1... Was that what you meant? It seems to work now.

Comment: No pageTSConfig. TypoScript setup. But you got it. Maybe read more here: http://elmars-typo3-knowledge-collection.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Extbase/StoragePid.html . I guess you have something like plugin.tx_kundentermine_pi.persistence.storagePid = {$plugin.tx_kundentermine_pi.persistence.storagePid} in your TypoScript setup